How do I attach the vscode debugger to a privileged process in WSL?
I'm learning raw sockets in C (and I'm lost at this point, but that's not entirely relevant here) and I'm trying to debug what's wrong. There's just one problem, I'm using WSL and my vscode does not have the root permissions. This is what I've tried:
sudo code . (to launch as root)
Result: sudo code not found ... I'm guessing this is because my vscode is installed in Windows' user space (or whatever jerry-rigged thing WSL does to access the Windows' vscode from linux) as code . works perfectly fine.
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }

Result:

I tried Googling, but it's not really helpful:

I do not want this to be an XY-Problem. So I guess what I really need to know is how to debug privileged processes with WSL and VSCODE.
